# jquery: Count characters, give different count to some tags

Tags: jquery, counting

I have code that counts characters in a textarea, any character, space, whatever will count as '1'. This works fine. However I want to count some strings differently:

- letters, chars, space = 1 character
- `&nbsp;` = 1 character
- `<li>` = 3 characters
- `<br>` or `<br/>` = 50 characters
- `<ol>`, `</ol>`, `<ul>`, `</ul>`, `</li>` = 0 characters

This is the normal 1 as 1 code:

```
   <textarea id="field" onkeyup="countChar(this)"></textarea>
    <div id="charNum"></div>

$('#field').keyup(function () {
  var max = 100;
  var len = $(this).val().length;
  if (len >= max) {
    $('#charNum').text(' that\'s the limit');
  } else {
    var char = max - len;
    $('#charNum').text(char + ' characters left');
  }
});
```

The snipped editor here worked (but gave me lots of errors): https://jsfiddle.net/yello/bq7rez9t/

I am not clear how to do that, vaguely I believe that `length` is the key to it.   So vaguely I believe I could count just all characters, and then deduct 5 for each `&nbsp;` and add 46 for a `<br>` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea worked. Use regular expressions to count the special cases and multiply the difference.

```js
$('#field').keyup(function () {
  var max = 100;
  var txt = $(this).val();
  var len = txt.length;
  var cnt=txt.match(/<li>/g); // <li>
  len-=cnt?cnt.length:0;
  cnt=txt.match(/<(u|o)l>/g); // <ul> and <ol>
  len-=cnt?cnt.length*4:0;
  cnt=txt.match(/(<\/((u|o)l|li)>|&nbsp;)/g); // </ul>, </ol>, </li> and &nbsp;
  len-=cnt?cnt.length*5:0;
  cnt=txt.match(/<br\/>/g); // <br/>
  len+=cnt?cnt.length*45:0;
  cnt=txt.match(/<br>/g); // <br>
  len+=cnt?cnt.length*46:0;
  if (len >= max) {
    $('#charNum').text(' that\'s the limit');
  } else {
    var char = max - len;
    $('#charNum').text(char + ' characters left');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="field"></textarea>
   <div id="charNum"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted. For those who wonder why - this is how eBay counts characters.

Comment: It was quick and dirty and could definitely be cleaned up. Also, anything starting with an ampersand and ending with a semicolon should be considered a single character.

Comment: eBay has their very own counting logic: https://pages.ebay.com/sell/itemdescription/customizeyoursummary.html